# how to properly implement different views options of the same data set

Tags: qt, mvvm

I'm currently building a model view architecture and came across an issue I can't find information on across the internet.

I have one set of complex data, that I want to show to the user in two (or more) different fashions :

- full data is shown
- only selected (partial) information in shown

The way this data is printed is to me irrelevant, but if this help it's either in a table view (basic information) or a column view (full information). those two clases comes from QT model / view framework.

Now I though about two option to implement this and wonder the one I should use

Option 1

- I build my data structure,
- include it in a custom model
- specialize (subclass) view classes in order to only print what I'm interrested in.

Option 2

- I build my data structure,
- specialize my models to only provide access to relevant data
- use standart view to print it on screen.

I would honestly go for option 2, but seeing the amount of case over the internet where option 1 is used I started to wonder if I'm doing it right. (I never found any example of dual model of a data when multiple view of a model appears to be quite frequent)

Placing data relevant handling inside view classes seem wrong to me, but duplicating models of a data leads to either duplicated data (which also seems wrong) or shared data (and then model no longer 'hold' the data)

I also had a look on QT delegates, but those class are mostly meant to change the appearence of data. I didn't find a way using delegates to ignore the data that is not relevant for one view.

Comment: Its important what you mean by 'selected data'. Do you mean leaving out some columns from all the records, leaving out some rows, or both?

Comment: From QT perspective it's neither row nor column, but children elements that should be filtered out. A row's row if you prefer, with Associated column data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely right thinking that it's wrong to use views for filtering data. The only reasons for reimplementing a view is to have a different view of the same data or special processing of user events.

So there are two ways to filter out a data:

1.Create two models which will share the data. It's a standard [recommended](http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/13/28/view) approach - not to keep data in models.

2.Create one model providing all the data and create a proxy model inherited from `QSortFilterProxyModel` to filter out the data.

You will need to reimplement `filterAcceptsColumn` method to filter out columns and `filterAcceptsRow` to filter out rows.

Then use `View-Model` to show all the data or `View-Proxy-Model` to show some data.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I took quite a liking of QSortFilterProxyModel  class, I'm gonna have a deeper look in it. It look like a standar implementation of a dual model approach. I also appreciate the link on data handling, QT model view doc misslead me to think models were actualy supposed to 'hold' the data.